# PHP Regex: how to remove some of the words in the link

Tags: php, regex

this is my first post. I already some days I tried but did not succeed.

Case: I want remove some of the words in the link from this link "[http://www.amazon.com/Mindfulness-Be-mindful-Live-moment/dp/0857084445/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443534574&sr=1-1&keywords=Mindfulness+Be+Mindful+Live+In+The+Moment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0857084445)"

this is my code

```
<?php 
$s = 'http://www.amazon.com/Mindfulness-Be-mindful-Live-moment/dp/0857084445/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443534574&sr=1-1&keywords=Mindfulness+Be+Mindful+Live+In+The+Moment';
preg_match("/http:/(.*)//", $s, $results);
echo $results[0];
?>
```

No for substr function cause the link is dynamic.
I want keep "0857084445" using php regex. Your solution really helped me. Thank you

Comment: What's the exact output that do you want from the script?
`http://www.amazon.com/Mindfulness-Be-mindful-Live-moment/dp/0857084445/`
or only
`0857084445` ?

Comment: i would like to see answer of this question

Comment: let me know if this part always remain same ? `http://www.amazon.com/Mindfulness-Be-mindful-Live-moment/dp/`

Comment: Is the number always in the same place, would using explode() on / and accessing the relevant key do the job?

Comment: no but always using this pattern http://www.amazon.com/xxxx/dp/

Comment: That doesn't match what you've got in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this regex `#/(\d+)/#i` that matches every digits between 2 /.

Not only your regexp is wrong, but the output of reults too. Since `$results[0]` contains the matched string. `$results[1]` the first caputured group and so on..

Here's the corrected code

```
<?php 
$s = 'http://www.amazon.com/Mindfulness-Be-mindful-Live-moment/dp/0857084445/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443534574&sr=1-1&keywords=Mindfulness+Be+Mindful+Live+In+The+Moment';
preg_match('#/(\d+)/#', $s, $results);
echo $results[1];
?>
```

Comment: And it will output `0857084445` but if links or place of number changed then it will give you wrong output

Comment: what are the hashtags for ?

Comment: anyway it wont work if you will have a digit in text before this number, you should use `'/dp\/(\d+)\//'` instead

Comment: the # sign is a regex delimiter, the same of /. But with # you should't escape /, thus the regex is easy to read.
Btw it will work with every digits placed between two / (try it). It's not necessary to change the regexp.

Comment: You are right. But why do you use case insensitive mode?

Comment: My fault. In this case the I modifier is totally useless. I'm going to edit. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If your question pertains to display purposes only, it would be a lot easier to do something like this since regex would not be needed.

```
<?php
$s = 'http://www.amazon.com/Mindfulness-Be-mindful-Live-moment/dp/0857084445/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443534574&sr=1-1&keywords=Mindfulness+Be+Mindful+Live+In+The+Moment';
?> <a href="<?php echo $s?>"> Whatever you want here</a>
```

Edit: I would have asked if it was for display only in the comments section, if I had 50 rep.